# setTextSize doesn't work with AutofitTextView in Android

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm using `AutofitTextView` and can't change text size on runtime. My XML:

```
<me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:text="Select Item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textSize="85sp"
    autofit:minTextSize="16sp"
    autofit:sizeToFit="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#fa0"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    />
```

My code:

```
 AutofitTextView header = (AutofitTextView) findViewById(R.id.header);
 header.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 25);
```

Code works when I changed XML tags to `TextView` but I need it to work with `AutofitTextView` also. Any idea?

Comment: Please post AutofitTextView java file

Comment: Because there should be dynamic text size handled in `AutofitTextView` .that's why `setTextSize()` method not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like

For fix size [No Auto]

```
header.setMinTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,25);
header.setMaxTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,25);
```

For Auto [ Range will be between 16 to 25 ]

```
header.setMinTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,16);
header.setMaxTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,25);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [AutofitHelper](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview/blob/master/library/src/main/java/me/grantland/widget/AutofitHelper.java) to set textsize at runtime as follows :

```
// when resizing textview
header.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 25)
AutofitHelper autofitHelper = AutofitHelper.create(header);
autofitHelper.setTextSize(header.getTextSize());
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: Kishore's answer also works and easier. Thanks anyway :)